# How to abort uiautomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

How can i abort android [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html) that is running an automation script?
The only way i found so far is to kill the "uiautomator" process directly using ADB shell.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

For `Runtime.getRuntime()` case, You can try below workaround:

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a lot of ways to kill uiautomator. I do CTRL + c from command line when I need it.

But why do you need to abord uiautomator ? If tests are to long, you can create several test cases or just run a function from a test case.

```
adb shell runtest ...TestCase1#test1
adb shell runtest ...TestCase1#test2
adb shell runtest ...TestCase2#test1
```

Comment: CTRL+C is applicable when running from command line. Currently i'm running from Runtime.getRuntime(). For my case, there is a need for me to stop it half way.